# package manager problem ubuntu 22.10

Tags: package-management, authentication

After installation of Ubuntu 22.10, Synaptic Package Manager cannot start because authentication fails. Password was cleared after installation of previous version, so no password was previous required for authentication. After upgrade SPM asks for authentication upon launch but will not execute, even if previously removed password is entered. Muon is able to start but the same problem exists when I try to apply changes. How can I eliminate the authentication requirement for these programs? Thank you.

Comment: That's right. This system boots without a password. Previously I was able to install and remove applications without a password.

Comment: I hope that the question is clearer now